# problem with regex (find page if given)

Tags: regex, conditional-statements

I've got the these strings:

```
/search/keyword.html
```

and

```
/search/keyword/1.html  # the 1 represents the current page
```

Now I want to write a regex that matches the keyword, and the page, if given.

`$1` (the first match) should always be the keyword (keyword).

`$2` should be the page, if there is one (1).

I tried this but it doesn't work correctly:

```
~/search/((.*)/(\d*)|(.*)).html~
```

`$1` is not always the keyword and `$2` not the page (if given).

Comment: What regex flavour are you using? Each language has some differences in the syntax, so it's important to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
~/search/([^/.]*)(?:/(\d+))?\.html~
```

Explanation:

```
/search/      # match /search/ literally
([^/.]*)      # match any number of characters except . or /, capture in backref 1
(?:           # if present...
 /(\d+)       # match a / and one or more digits, capture the latter in backref 2
)?            # ...end of optional group
\.html        # match .html literally
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your regexp flavor:

```
,^/search/([^/]+)/(.*)\.[^.]+$,
```